# How do the punishments to each of the Trustees correspond to the 7 deadly sins' punishments?

Tags: keys-to-the-kingdom

In the Keys to The Kingdom, all of the trustees correspond to a different deadly sin:

> The Lower House — Ruled by Mister Monday who is afflicted by Sloth
>
> The Far Reaches — Ruled by Grim Tuesday who is afflicted by Greed
>
> The Border Sea — Ruled by Drowned Wednesday who is afflicted by Gluttony
>
> The Great Maze — Ruled by Sir Thursday who is afflicted by Wrath
>
> The Middle House — Ruled by Lady Friday who is afflicted by Lust
>
> The Upper House — Ruled by Superior Saturday who is afflicted by Envy
>
> The Incomparable Gardens — Ruled by Lord Sunday who is afflicted by Pride

There is a list of the punishments on [Christianity SE:](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/what-are-the-punishments-for-the-seven-deadly-sins)

> Pride - You will be broken on the wheel
>
> Envy - Placed in freezing water
>
> Gluttony - Force fed rats, toads and snakes
>
> Lust - Covered in fire and brimstone
>
> Anger - Live dismemberment
>
> Greed - Boiled in oil
>
> Sloth - Thrown into a snake pit

I noticed that in the first book, Monday gets devoured by snakes as a punishment. Is this true for the rest of the books as well?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, they don't. For instance, Saturday is never thrown into any water, nor Grim Tuesday boiled. Rather, what happens to *Arthur*, at least sometimes, figuratively or  literally fits these descriptions, though not all of them seem to follow this analogy.

In *Mr. Monday*, Arthur *also* has to traverse the snake pit.

In *Grim Tuesday*, he's kind of boiled:

> "Don't come back to me," muttered Arthur under his breath as he
>   clambered up.    At the top, he turned and reached back to help Suzy.
>   The water was really   boiling now all along the sunship, and Arthur
>   could see a red glow spreading through the clear blue-green sea.

In *Drowned Wednesday*, it's unclear whether there's an analogy. Instead of swallowing rats, Arthur is himself swallowed, and there are a lot of Raised Rats.

*Sir Thursday* is an interesting case. He's not literally dismembered; rather, the Bathroom attendents figuratively take him apart by suppressing his memories.

In *Lady Friday*, there's a lot of heat mentioned, but it's not really an obstacle or punishment as such.

In *Superior Saturday*, he falls into the (presumably cold) storm reservoir.

In *Lord Sunday*, he's tortured by tying him to a clock that will mutilate him (though the actual torture is more the threat of this than anything else). In the medieval punishment of breaking on the wheel, people would be tied to a wheel that would torture them through mutilation.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind givin gthis a go as well? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216956/do-each-of-the-afflictions-that-occur-to-arthurs-family-and-to-earth-correspond

Comment: @TheAsh - I already checked. As obvious as it would be, I don't think there's any connection there. The logical correlation is the seven seals, trumpets, or bowls from Revelation, but they don't seem to match.